# Dell Premier Collaboration Keyboard KB900 on Ubuntu with wireless USB

Tags: usb, 22.04, dell

I've got a Dell Premier Collaboration Keyboard KB900.
It's working with bluetooth but not with the wireles usb dongle.

Ubuntu 22.04

```
uname -a
```

Linux 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu

```
lsusb
```

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 413c:2119 Dell Computer Corp. Dell Secure Link Receiver

```
dmesg -a
```

[22102.142282] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 2

[22108.005310] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd

[22108.179090] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2119, bcdDevice=41.78
[22108.179098] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

[22108.179103] usb 5-1: Product: Dell Secure Link Receiver

[22108.179107] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: Dell Computer Corp

[22108.179111] usb 5-1: SerialNumber: 76D13DA695CC75A9

[22108.228428] input: Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:413C:2119.0014/input/input53

[22108.285747] hid-generic 0003:413C:2119.0014: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver] on usb-0000:0c:00.3-1/input0

[22108.292470] input: Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:413C:2119.0015/input/input54

[22108.292693] input: Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:413C:2119.0015/input/input55

[22108.349445] input: Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:413C:2119.0015/input/input56

[22108.349610] hid-generic 0003:413C:2119.0015: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver] on usb-0000:0c:00.3-1/input1

[22108.356343] hid-generic 0003:413C:2119.0016: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver] on usb-0000:0c:00.3-1/input2

[22108.364584] hid-generic 0003:413C:2119.0017: hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver] on usb-0000:0c:00.3-1/input3

```
switching from bluetooth to wireless usb and back to bluetooth
```

[22643.343490] Bluetooth: hci0: ACL packet for unknown connection handle 16

[22643.343500] Bluetooth: hci0: ACL packet for unknown connection handle 16

[22643.343505] Bluetooth: hci0: ACL packet for unknown connection handle 16

[22661.077323] input: Dell Keyboard KB900  Keyboard as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:413C:211A.0018/input/input57

[22661.077815] hid-generic 0005:413C:211A.0018: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v10.42 Keyboard [Dell Keyboard KB900 ] on 44:01:bb:a8:7d:c8

```
input list
```

Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver System Control id=17 [slave keyboard (3)]

Dell Computer Corp Dell Secure Link Receiver Consumer Control id=22 [slave keyboard (3)]

Answer (score 0):

With a Windows 11 pc I have updated the usb dongle and the keyboard to the latest firmware.

It's working now in Ubuntu 22.04

I'm not sure you can update the firmware with linux, I didn't check.